# Java getimage() method does not load image

Tags: java

Java `getImage()` does not load image. 
The code is following :

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Draw extends java.applet.Applet
{
    Image mg;

    public void init()
    {
        mg = getImage(getdocumentBase(), "java.gif");       

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(mg,5,45,this);

    }
}
```

the image would not load even if you added absolute path

Comment: How do you know? I mean what have you tried to find the error so far, what is your error message etc?

Comment: Is "java.gif" valid path?

Comment: Seems like your project doesn't have `java.gif` file.

Comment: [Do Java applets have any place on the web today?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154537/do-java-applets-have-any-place-on-the-web-today)

Comment: Any stacktrace?

Comment: is init() called? if it's a API method from Applet do add @Override into declaration

Comment: what does @override do